# i have created the wizard, i want it to position always at the center, can any one help me?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

```
private Point getFirstMonitorSize() { // Here Point is org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    if (display != null) {
        Monitor[] monitors = display.getMonitors();
        if (monitors.length == 1) {
            Rectangle clientArea = monitors[0].getClientArea();
            return new Point(clientArea.width / 2, clientArea.height / 2);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I found out this for positioning but i don't know how to use in wizard dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position your wizard dialog by calling `wizardDialog.getShell().setLocation(..)`.

Answer (score 3):

For Eclipse E4, you can add this method in your E4LifeCycle class.
This will make your application centre of primary monitor.

This will make your application shell location in centre of screen, this if you open the WizardDialog where you set the proper `parent shell` then every thing will fall into place

```java
@Inject
@Optional
public void receiveActiveShell(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) final Shell shell) {
    try {
        if (shell != null) {
            final Display display = shell.getDisplay();
            final Monitor primary = display.getPrimaryMonitor();
            final Rectangle displayBounds = primary.getBounds();
            shell.setSize(displayBounds.width - 100, displayBounds.height - 100);
            final Point size = shell.getSize();
            Point defaultLocation = new Point((int) (displayBounds.width - size.x) / 2, (int) (displayBounds.height - size.y) / 2);
            shell.setLocation(this.defaultLocation);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Execption ocuured in Active Shell", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
}
```